Swagger - How does one get it to denote the Primary Key?
Here's a GET, that on Success (200), it returns a response model.
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 and .net6.0 if that matters ..
When you look at the Swagger documentation, even though the model has the [Key] annotation, this is what it looks like in Swagger:

I'd love for it to say that ID is the Primary Key.
edit: I know in the model, if you do the triple slash comment near the field, it will present your comment, where you can say "this is the Primary Key", or that these two fields are the "composite key", but I was surprised Swagger didn't just pick up on [Key] and denote it in some way.

How is defined your API entry point (and useful related class / DTO classes)?

@Pac0 - Umm, not sure what you mean.  In this example, we just put together a small model class just as an example.  So, it's right-click, new Model, add some fields to the class, etc.  And return from the GET end-point.

OpenAPI Specification does not have the concept of "primary key", but, as you've noted you can mention any relevant info in the description of a model or field.

Thanks @Helen.  It's so weird, because for our "required" annotation, it picks up on it and adds the red star.  But it hates [Key]! lol

Feel free to file an enhancement request with the .NET library (Swashbuckle?) that you use to generate an OpenAPI definition from code.
